# SQL GROUP and CASE statement convert row into column

Tags: sql-server, case, grouping

[image]

how to convert like this row into column

Comment: Some [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please, CREATE TABLE and INSERT VALUES would really help.

Comment: What you are looking for is a `pivot`. [Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server) is the answer for your question.

Comment: Attention to readers, column 1 is case-sensitive, column 2 skips some values, e.g. 304 skipped since for the same column 1 value, 305 exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
select model_cod, ver_num, 
sum(case when mod_cls in ('KM', 'KS') then cost else 0 end) as [KM/KS],
sum(case when mod_cls ='PL' then cost else 0 end) as PL,
sum(case when mod_cls ='PI' then cost else 0 end) as PI,
sum(case when mod_cls in ('KM', 'KS', 'PL', 'PI') then cost else 0 end) as Total
from yourtable
group by model_cod, ver_num
```

Comment: Error
token sum was not valid. valid token:, from into

Comment: what is the type of 'cost' column? Always numbers into this column?

Comment: Thanks Bro Its Working

Comment: 'cost' column' decimal